# sql - single line per distinct values in a given column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

is there a way using sql, in bigquery more specifically, to get one line per unique value in a given column

I know that this is possible using a sequence of union queries where you have as much union as distinct values as there is in the column of interest. but i'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.* except (seqnum)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col order by col) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns an arbitrary row.  You can control *which* row by adjusting the `order by`.

Another fun solution in BigQuery uses structs:

```
select array_agg(t limit 1)[ordinal(1)].*
from t
group by col;
```

You can add an `order by` (`order by X limit 1`) if you want a particular row.

Answer (score 0):

here is just a more formated format :

```
select tab.* except(seqnum)
from (
 select *, row_number() over (partition by column_x order by column_x) as seqnum
 from `project.dataset.table`
) as tab
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY col
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 col UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 3 
)
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY col
```

with result

```
Row id  col  
1   1   1    
2   4   2    
3   6   3
```